# Errors when using the fetch function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I'm working with AWS API Gateway and I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch

My API is just returning a simple JSON string. I can get a successful response with curl, Postman and testing via the AWS console. But, using JavaScript, I get an error. I suspect that AWS requires a specific header

I separated the code from the original website. Some unnecessary parts have been removed.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
const GET_url = '<url>'
const POST_url = '<url>'

async function getInvokeFromAPI() {
  const response = await fetch(GET_url, {
    method: 'GET'
  });
  const data = await response.json();
}

async function postInvokeFromAPI() {
  const respone = await fetch(POST_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  });
  const data = await response.json();
}
</script>
```

Comment: what does your browser dev tools show?

Comment: The error is below, I just remove the references to the line.
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at getInvokeFromAPI 
    at <anonymous>
    --- await ---
    at <anonymous>

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the console output when the error happens.

But if it works with Postman and not with the fetch API, you are probably having a CORS error.

You can check this page of the MDN for more informations about CORS in case it is your error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

If it is your error, it will be logged in the browser console in the dev tools.